# What is this error message mean and how to fix it

Tags: c++

I receive the following error message:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in GDIMario.exe
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in GDIMario.exe or any of the DLLs is has loaded.
>
> This my also be due to the user pressing F12 while GDIMario.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

[image: Here is an image hosted in imageshack]

I really don't know why I've this caution, I don't F12. thanks for reading this ;)

Comment: I assume GDIMario.exe is your own program? Then what happens if you click on *Break* and have a look at the output window?

Comment: For gods sake show us the offending code! You've most likely deleted something twice, used a dangling pointer or written past the end of an array.

Answer (score 2):

Googling around for "Windows has triggered a breakpoint in ...."

Shows a myriad of possible reasons including:

- Mismatched DLL versions
- Thread Access
- Issues Heap Corruption.
- Win32 compatibility with Vista

If possible, I recommend stepping through your program in the debugger and see if its a memory corruption.

Also, perhaps trying to run your application in Compatibility Mode (if you're running Vista or Win7)

Comment: If your program uses your own DLL, make sure you are using the same version as your program - for example if you create a debug DLL and compile your program in release mode, this is probably the cause of the above error.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is probably the important one. Windows is telling you that you have corrupted the heap of your program, and you should fix the problem.

You can run your program under the debugger to find out more precisely where the error occurred.